# Total Commander: Comparing files is slow because of Microsoft Defender Antivirus

Tags: windows-defender, total-commander

I use [Total Commander](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_Commander) and [Microsoft Defender Antivirus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Defender).

I noticed that comparing directories in Total Commander (go to `Commands > Synchronize Dirs ...`, select the "*by content*" checkbox, and press the "*Compare*" button) is slow, because the antivirus uses most of the CPU to scan the files being compared:

[image]

If I configure Microsoft Defender to not monitor Total Commander process i.e. if I set:
`Windows Settings > Update & Security > Windows Security > Virus & threat protection > Manage settings > Add or remove exclusions > Add an exclusion > Process` to: `C:\Program Files\totalcmd\TOTALCMD64.EXE`, then the directory comparison is much faster:

[image]

[image]

Is it safe to add the `C:\Program Files\totalcmd\TOTALCMD64.EXE` process exclusion in Microsoft Defender?

Comment: I compared some sizable folders and the sync / compare did not seem slow to me. Windows Defender is not interfering.  Are you using Total Commander V9.5 or 9.5.1 and are you using the 64-bit version (will be faster)

Comment: I am using Total Commander 9.51 64-bit and up-to-date Windows 10 ver. 2004.

Comment: I am not having any issues with it.  Are the folders you are syncing fully scanned with Windows Defender?

Comment: @John, Yes, I made the Full scan a few days ago.

Comment: To be sure, I scanned both directories again (right mouse click on the directory > Scan with Microsoft Defender ...). Although the directories were scanned a minute ago, Microsoft Defender scans them again during comparing files in Total Commander.

Comment: A bit of a shot in the dark. Try adding quick search extended.   https://ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?p=327609#327609

Comment: @John: Why would that help? Searching for text in a file is different from comparing the entire content of files.

Comment: I thought it might help the T.C. installation. Purely a shot in the dark.

Answer (score 0):

Anti-virus programs that offer real-time protection are meant to live at the first line of defense. In this case, you have to ask yourself if Total Commander is handling files that are freshly downloaded from the internet, or if you are using it for other file operations with safe files.

If you are using Total Commander as your main File Explorer, or as a Windows Explorer replacement, it might not be a good idea to add it to your list of exclusions.

Comment: No need for that here. Defender does not get in the way of either machine I have here with Total Commander. Both machines Windows 10 V2004 up to date

Comment: Windows Defender usually only causes slowdowns on drives that have lower read/write speed. These include flash memory, hybrid drives, and older 5400/7200 RPM drives. If you are running your system with Total Commander on an SSD or better, you might not be experiencing the slow down that OP is having.

Comment: I don't use anything as slow as 5400-rpm, but both hard drives (one machine) and SSD another.

Comment: @iskyfire: I have SSD, not HDD. If you look on the screenshoot of my Task Manager, then you will see that the CPU slows down Microsoft Defender, not the disk.

Comment: It's possible that you and John used different methods of installation for Total Commander. Maybe Windows flagged the application as being "Downloaded from the Internet" for you, but not for John. That's why you had to add it to the list of exclusions.

Comment: I downloaded "64-bit version only" instalator from: https://www.ghisler.com/download.htm. Then I ran the installer normally (not as the administrator), and allowed it to be installed in the [User Account Control](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) window.